# Log final MySQL query in MyBatis Java to execute it manually afterwards on a different server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, log4j, mybatis

I am developing a command line application in JAVA where, based on some factors, MySQL queries are executed on a sandbox MySQL server and after some manual verification these queries need to be executed on the production server. I want to log these MySQL queries in a .sql file on sandbox server and execute it later using scripts.

I tried searching through stack overflow and found lots of examples for logging queries, but the queries logged are not the final queries executed. For example,

```
Preparing: INSERT into table_name values(null, ?,?, ?,?,?, ?, ?,?); 
DEBUG [pool-4-thread-1] - ==> Parameters: 21655(Integer), 2658413(Integer), 04:05:00(Time), null, 1565.0(Double), 3(String), (String), 0(Integer)
```

Also, the queries are not logged in directly executable format.

My log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.logger.com.test.mappers.TableMapper=TRACE
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] - %m%n
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement=DEBUG, stdout

log4j.logger.com.ibatis.common.jdbc.SimpleDataSource=DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.ibatis.common.jdbc.ScriptRunner=DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientDelegate=DEBUG

log4j.logger.com.ibatis=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.Connection=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.Statement=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.ResultSet=DEBUG
```

Can I log exact final MySQL queries in a .sql file separately?

Comment: can you share your code please?

Comment: @YCF_L Thanks for replying, I found a solution for this by using log4jdbc-log4j2 and using custom log delegator which logs exact Mysql query in a separate file.

Comment: you can post the solution as an answer maybe it help others in future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot, I found that this is not possible only with Mybatis and log4j, it needs a proxy driver which can log the request to JDBC driver.

I found the idea of using [log4jdbc2](http://log4jdbc.brunorozendo.com) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41001188/spring-boot-with-spring-mybatis-how-to-force-it-to-logging-all-sql-queries) with **LOG4JDBC_SQL** marker to send the SQL queries to a separate file. But, this file will contain approximated time taken for execution and connection number also. So to get rid of them I wrote a custom spy log delegator.

Installation and configuration of log4jdbc2 can be found [here](http://log4jdbc.brunorozendo.com).

I will rewrite the steps taken for getting the desired results:

- Added maven dependency for log4jdbc2. log4jdbc2 depends on log4j-api and log4j-core, make sure they are included in the project.

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1</artifactId>
      <version>1.16</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Changed JDBC URL from `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb` to `jdbc:log4jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb`
- Changed the driver used to `net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy`
- Created an appender and created a logger with **LOG4JDBC_SQL** marker to filter only sql queries.

  ```
  <Appenders>
      <File name="queryLog" fileName="/Users/sahebpreetsingh/queries.sql"
      immediateFlush="false" append="false">
          <PatternLayout pattern="%msg%n" />
      </File>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
      <logger name="log4jdbc.log4j2" level="info" additivity="false">
          <MarkerFilter marker="LOG4JDBC_SQL" onMatch="ACCEPT"
          onMismatch="DENY" />
          <appender-ref ref="queryLog" />
      </logger>
  </Loggers>
  ```

  The marker here specifies to filter sql queries only and ignore the rest of the results.
- Extended the existing Log4j2SpyLogDelegator to save time and log only sql queries in executable form.

  ```
  package com.myapp.utils;

  import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
  import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
  import org.apache.logging.log4j.Marker;
  import org.apache.logging.log4j.MarkerManager;

  import net.sf.log4jdbc.Properties;
  import net.sf.log4jdbc.log.log4j2.Log4j2SpyLogDelegator;
  import net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.Spy;

  public class QueryLogDelegator extends Log4j2SpyLogDelegator {

      private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger("log4jdbc.log4j2");

      private static final Marker SQL_MARKER = MarkerManager.getMarker("LOG4JDBC_SQL");

      private static final Marker SELECT_MARKER = MarkerManager.getMarker("LOG4JDBC_SELECT", SQL_MARKER);

      private static final Marker INSERT_MARKER = MarkerManager.getMarker("LOG4JDBC_INSERT", SQL_MARKER);

      private static final Marker UPDATE_MARKER = MarkerManager.getMarker("LOG4JDBC_UPDATE", SQL_MARKER);

      private static final Marker DELETE_MARKER = MarkerManager.getMarker("LOG4JDBC_DELETE", SQL_MARKER);

      private static final Marker CREATE_MARKER = MarkerManager.getMarker("LOG4JDBC_CREATE", SQL_MARKER);

      private String getSqlOperation(String sql) {
          if (sql == null) {
              return "";
          }
          sql = sql.trim();

          if (sql.length() < 6) {
              return "";
          }
          return sql.substring(0, 6).toLowerCase();
      }

      private boolean shouldSqlBeLogged(String operation) {
          return ((operation == null) || ((Properties.isDumpSqlSelect()) && ("select".equals(operation)))
                  || ((Properties.isDumpSqlInsert()) && ("insert".equals(operation))) || ((Properties.isDumpSqlUpdate()) && ("update".equals(operation)))
                  || ((Properties.isDumpSqlDelete()) && ("delete".equals(operation))) || ((Properties.isDumpSqlCreate()) && ("create".equals(operation))));
      }

      @Override
      public void sqlTimingOccurred(Spy spy, long execTime, String methodCall, String sql) {
          String operation = getSqlOperation(sql);
          if ((Properties.isDumpSqlFilteringOn()) && (!(shouldSqlBeLogged(operation)))) {
              return;
          }

          Marker marker = getStatementMarker(operation);

          if ((Properties.isSqlTimingErrorThresholdEnabled()) && (execTime >= Properties.getSqlTimingErrorThresholdMsec())) {
              LOGGER.error(marker, sql);
          } else if (LOGGER.isWarnEnabled())
              if ((Properties.isSqlTimingWarnThresholdEnabled()) && (execTime >= Properties.getSqlTimingWarnThresholdMsec())) {
                  LOGGER.warn(marker, sql);
              } else
                  LOGGER.info(marker, sql);
      }

      private Marker getStatementMarker(String operation) {
          if (operation == null)
              return SQL_MARKER;
          if ("select".equals(operation))
              return SELECT_MARKER;
          if ("insert".equals(operation))
              return INSERT_MARKER;
          if ("update".equals(operation))
              return UPDATE_MARKER;
          if ("delete".equals(operation))
              return DELETE_MARKER;
          if ("create".equals(operation)) {
              return CREATE_MARKER;
          }
          return SQL_MARKER;
      }

  }
  ```
- Added the logger to log4jdbc.log4j2.properties

  ```
  log4jdbc.dump.sql.addsemicolon=true
  log4jdbc.spylogdelegator.name=com.myapp.QueryLogDelegator
  ```