# MyBatis can't set arguments on query

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

Mybatis throws an error which says there is problem with setting params. What could be wrong? I tested the SQL query and it's fine. I'm using graddle with spring.

> Error querying database.
>   Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near
>   "customer"   Position: 245
>   The error may exist in services/CustomerService.java (best guess)
>   The error may involve services.CustomerService.findByPersonalCodeAndCountry-Inline
>   The error occurred while setting parameters

Code:

```
import com.luminor.dc.ccc.contracts.dao.Customer;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Select;
@Mapper
public interface CustomerService {


    @Select("Select * FROM customer WHERE cust_personal_code= #{personalCode} AND cust_bank_country = #{country}")
    List<Customer> findByPersonalCodeAndCountry(@Param("personalCode") String personalCode,@Param("country") String country);
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/customers", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public class CustomerController {

   private CustomerService customerService;

    public CustomerController(@Autowired CustomerService customerService) {
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{personalCode}")
    public List<Customer> getCustomersByPersonalCode(@PathVariable String personalCode, @RequestHeader String country) {
        return customerService.findByPersonalCodeAndCountry(personalCode, country);
    }
}
```

Table

Comment: This error usually happens if the query is syntactically incorrect, e.g. `select * customer where ...`. May it be that you had incorrect query, then fix it but still are running the old code? I would suggest to enable queries logging (in mybatis or in postgres) and check what query is really sent and executed in DB.

Comment: try using db level logging,useful link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41001188/spring-boot-with-spring-mybatis-how-to-force-it-to-logging-all-sql-queries/41234831

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you try below code ?

```
Controller method :
     @GetMapping("/{personalCode}")
        public List<Customer> getCustomersByPersonalCode(@PathVariable String personalCode, @RequestHeader(value="country") String country) {
            return customerService.findByPersonalCodeAndCountry(personalCode, country);
        }

@Results(value = { @Result(column = "id", property = "id"), 
        @Result(column = "cust_personal_code", property = "personalCode"), 
        @Result(column = "cust_bank_country ", property = "country")
    )}
    @Select("Select * FROM customer WHERE cust_personal_code= #{personalCode} AND cust_bank_country = #{country}")
    List<Customer> findByPersonalCodeAndCountry(@Param("personalCode") String personalCode, @Param("country") String country);
```

> where id, personalCode,country : variables in customer POJO
>   Table-> id(Integer),cust_personal_code (String ),cust_bank_country(String ) : columns in table

Comment: sorry about that, that comma was just typo when I was pasting code In here

Comment: Did you tried giving result set and whole code change?

Comment: @jodymilers can you provide table details? and also make sure you are importing the package "org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param"

Comment: added imports and table

Comment: @jodymilers table details ? type of columns ? i think the issue maybe with different datatypes in table and your parameter type

Comment: @jodymilers  i have updated the answer,can you please check and update whether that approach worked ?